# How to install a package/module/library in Postgresql 12 running on ubuntu server?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I want to use the postgresql-anonymizer library to do data masking on PostgreSQL 12.
Link: https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL/
Can someone guide me on how to install this package/library/module?

Comment: The section `Install With PGXN` describes ubuntu based installation

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.